# How to convert wordpress from english to japanese?

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site it is now in English, But i have to convert it completely in wordpress.

All posts, links,terms,taxonomy also db entries everything to japanese.

Can anyone suggest me how to do this, i dont want to use any plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is possible to change things like ur database (why would you even want to change the db entries?)

If u just donwload a good translate plugin and set the language to japanese, what problems do you have left then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a translate plugin and translate your site. I am using WPML (http://wpml.org/) translator but it is paid one.